# jQuery Get for PHP files

Tags: php, jquery, get

I have this statement in my jQuery file:

```
$.get("homeTemplates/randomVids.php", function(data){$("#hVid").html(data);});
```

Where the contents of randomVids.php should be loaded into a div called `hVid`. However, this does not work for me: nothing seems to load when the line is executed.

I consulted [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess - try adding a `/` before `homeTemplates` (i.e. make your path absolute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just use this...

```
$("#hVid").load("homeTemplates/randomVids.php");
```